# Confirm_password validation error not working

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I am relatively new to Django, so this may have a simple solution but I am very confused at this point.
I tried to validate if my password and confirm-password are same but the error message does not appear even when I type different passwords in confirm_password and password. I guess the is_valid is returning False but I cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

USER = get_user_model()


class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def clean_username(self):
        if USER.objects.filter(username=self.cleaned_data['username']).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This username is taken")
        return self.cleaned_data['username']

    def clean(self):
        try:
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']
            confirm_password = self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
            if password != confirm_password:
                raise forms.ValidationError("You passwords do not match")
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from accounts.forms import SignInForm, SignUpForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            user = User(
                username = form.cleaned_data['username'],
                email = form.cleaned_data['email'],
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            )
            user.save()
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return redirect('/accounts/signin/')
        else:
            print("Invalid")
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

my template

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sign-Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="sign-up-form">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="{%static 'images/Logo.png' %}" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <div class="sign-up">
          <h2>SIGN UP</h2>
          <form method="POST" class="box">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-box">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="USERNAME"
                class="form-box-box"
              />
            </div>
            {% for error in form.username.errors %} 
            <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
            {% endfor%}
            <div class="form-box">
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="EMAIL"
                class="form-box-box"
              />
            </div>
            {% for error in form.email.errors %} 
            <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
            {% endfor%}
            <div class="form-box">
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="PASSWORD"
                class="form-box-box"
              />
            </div>
            {% for error in form.password.errors %} 
            <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
            {% endfor%}
            <div class="form-box">
              <input
                type="password"
                name="confirm_password"
                placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD"
                class="form-box-box"
              />
            </div>
            {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %} 
            <small class="text-danger">{{error}}</small>
            {% endfor%}
            <div class="social-images">
              <img
                src="{%static 'images/Facebook.svg' %}"
                alt="facebook"
                class="social-list"
              />
              <img
                src="{%static 'images/linkedin.svg' %}"
                alt="linkedin"
                class="social-list"
              />
              <img
                src="{%static 'images/instagram.svg' %}"
                alt="instagram"
                class="social-list"
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="form-box-box button-box">
              SUBMIT
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="{%static 'images/Elephant.jpg' %}" alt="Elephant" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```